# Resolution of direct image functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, complex-geometry

Let $i: X \to Y$ be an embedding of compact complex manifolds (not necessarily projective) and $E\to X$ a holomorphic vector bundle.  I've seen it stated that the direct image sheaf $i_* E$ has a resolution by holomorphic vector bundles on $Y$.  Is there a nice, clean way to construct this resolution?  Or a good reference where this is discussed?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Most of my answer was total nonsense so I got rid of it but I think this paragraph is still true and still answers your question.**

I'll give an answer considering them as proper varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. I'm pretty sure this should then be true in the holomorphic case as well (maybe by GAGA though I can't say I understand that).

More generally, suppose we had any morphism of complex compact manifolds $f:X \to Y$ and any coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$. Again, $f$ is proper since $X$ and $Y$ are proper. Therefore, the pushforward $f_*\mathcal{F}$ is coherent on $Y$. Excersise III.6.8 of Hartshorne gurantees us the existence of a resolution by locally free sheaves and Hilbert's syzygy theorem gurantees it is finite.

For references see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71997/locally-free-resolution-of-coherent-sheaf) MO quetsion.

Comment: Dear @ Dori, *contra* what you say closed embeddings are **never** flat except in very exceptional or trivial circumstances. A vector  bundle on $X$ will have as direct image in $Y$ a sheaf supported on the image of $X$, which prevents it from being locally free on $Y$.

Comment: Oh wow you;re totally right. I was way too tired when I wrote that answer. Deleting the first half. I think the second part about the pushforward being coherent is still right correct?

Comment: I think this only holds for smooth submanifolds of $\mathbb CP^n$

Comment: Yes you do need smooth. I assumed that you meant smooth when you said manifold. I'm not sure if you still have finite resolutions in the nonsmooth case. I think that excersise in Hartshorne will still get you a resolution it just may not terminate. I don't think you need projective. Proper should be enough.

Comment: On second thought, I don't think the locally factorial hypothesis of that exercise will hold for singular things so I don't know even about infinite resolutions.